# Emacs Orgmode to MoinMoin converter

Tags: emacs, org-mode, moinmoin

I am looking for some way of automatic conversion of emacs org-mode file into moin-moin syntax. I couldn't find any direct converters.
Then my hope were converters like pandoc or txt2tags and indirect conversion with some intermediate format. However it does not look possible at the moment.

Do you have some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen [ox-mm](https://github.com/mbeckersys/ox-mm) and [org-moinmoin](https://github.com/derfian/org-moinmoin) and I haven't really assessed them, but they look promissing.  Org-moinmoin is the more current of the two.

I've been content to just use [MoinMoin's emacs script](https://moinmo.in/EmacsForMoinMoin) for the most part, which has syntax highlighting and outline support.